# How to match client time with server time in datepicker control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have two `text boxes` each having `date_picker` control. In one `text box` the date with time is automatically populating while loading the page.That time its taking the server Date
-time.And in second `text box` a user have to select the date-time but it is taking system time.And it is mismatching.

I want while user select a date-time its automatically convert to server time.How is it possible ? Can anyone say me ?

Comment: Paste ur code so we can provide solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the server's time but the user's selected date? If so, consider the following:

**C#**

```
DateTime ServerDateTime = new DateTime();
ServerDateTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime ClientDate = clientDateControl.Value;
DateTime AdjustedDateTime = new DateTime(ClientDate.Year, ClientDate.Month, ClientDate.Day, ServerDateTime.Hour, ServerDateTime.Minute, ServerDateTime.Second);
```

**VB**

```
Dim ServerDateTime As DateTime = New DateTime()
ServerDateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim ClientDate As DateTime = clientDateControl.Value
Dim AdjustedDateTime As DateTime = New DateTime(ClientDate.Year, ClientDate.Month, ClientDate.Day, ServerDateTime.Hour, ServerDateTime.Minute, ServerDateTime.Second)
```

Using this, you can either continue using the second date picker control and substitute its value for the ServerDateTime variable or you can remove the second date picker control as you already know the server datetime serverside.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I fully understand what you are trying to accomplish, but generally speaking this is what we have UTC for.

UTC is the global baseline date and time. Using javascript or whatever server side language it should be very simple to convert both dates to UTC and compare them.

Best of luck.